# trimming empty spaces in large table sql serever

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to trim a large table with more than 300 columns  dynamically. when i tried with this code i was getting an error because the variable @sql is of nvarchar(max) and i have like 300 columns so all the column names were not coming when i run this query can any of the guys help me in this ?

```
    DECLARE @SQL nVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
    SET @TableName = 'MYTAbleName'

    SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ',[', '[') + 
    COLUMN_NAME + ']=LTRIM(RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

      SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [' + @TableName + '] SET ' + @SQL
      PRINT @SQL
      EXECUTE @SQL
```

Comment: Should be `EXECUTE (@SQL)` not `EXECUTE @SQL`. Also use `QUOTENAME` instead of adding the square brackets yourself and this approach to string concatenation is not guaranteed.

Comment: Are all of the columns some sort of string data type? If not, you ought to filter on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE`. You can always make multiple passes, e.g. processing 100 columns at a time.

Answer (score 0):

While you have defined @SQL nvarchar(max), it all boils down to how a query is sent to the SQL server engine.

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) maximum capacity specifications.

"Network Packet Size is the size of the tabular data stream (TDS) packets used to communicate between applications and the relational Database Engine. The default packet size is 4 KB, and is controlled by the network packet size configuration option."

The Max batch size is 64 * 4 or 250 MB for a query to be submitted to the engine.  This is alot smaller than the (max) = 2GB.

Add a debugging line to see if you are coming close to this limitation.  Comment out printing the t-sql and executing the query.

```
-- Show how long the dynamic t-sql is
-- PRINT @SQL
PRINT 'LEN OF TSQL'
PRINT LEN(@SQL)
-- EXECUTE @SQL
```

Please report back if this is the issue!

I do not have a test case like yours.

```
-- Use msdb
USE MSDB
GO

-- Largest column count = 62, [sysutility_ucp_instances]
SELECT TABLE_NAME, MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) as MaxCols
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME 
order by MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) desc
```

Since your TSQL is getting cut off, it must be casting to a varchar() which has a max of 8000 bytes.

Try casting each piece of the update to varchar(max).

```
SET @SQL = cast('UPDATE [' as varchar(max)) + cast(@TableName as varchar(max)) + cast('] SET ' as varchar(max)) + @SQL;
```

Use varchar() instead of nvarchar to get one power of 2 back.

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: when i added the debuuging line it gave me like LEN OF TSQL
8595

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the actual tsql statement?  Also, I am wondering if the + operator with different variables (nvarchar(128), static text) is doing a implicit cast.  <br>I have to run but will look at it later ...

Comment: when i have run the above dynamic query with out execute(@SQL). It was giving me an update statement as my output. in which the statement was stopping in the middle with out completing all columns. is there any way for this ?

Comment: Did you try casting all parts of the update statement as a varchar(max)?  Please send me the create table code - right click in SSMS and generate T-SQL.  I am using 2012 on my laptop and was unable to cause a error.